# Fold/collapse sections in org agenda?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

A custom multi-section agenda view can get quite long.  Is there a built-in mechanism to fold or collapse sections like the standard outline view of org files to help with readability?

I'm interested in minimally being able to collapse individual sections of a multi-section agenda.

Answer (score 4):

I thought of this and found a solution today.  Having came here via the first result from Google, I though I'd share it.  The outline minor mode can be used to achieve this, exploiting the fact that the contents of individual agenda views are indented but the headers start from the first column:

```lisp
    (setq-local outline-regexp "^[A-Z]")
    (setq-local outline-heading-end-regexp ".$")
    (setq-local outline-minor-mode-prefix "C-'")
    (outline-minor-mode)
    (local-set-key outline-minor-mode-prefix outline-mode-prefix-map)
```

Comment: this is a pretty neat idea, just as FYI addition `yafolding-mode`- which folds based on indentation- is able to do this off-the-shelf, including disclosure triangles.

Comment: Thank you, works great! Had to write `(setq-local outline-minor-mode-prefix (kbd "C-'"))` to make it work for me.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such mechanism for org agendas.  However, there is `org-sparse-tree` (`C-c /`) which will do and agenda-like search and instead of creating a new agenda buffer, will fold your org file to show only matching entries.  However, your searches will be more limited than with `org-agenda`

Comment: `org-sparse-tree` is generally too limited.  Folding below the top "level" of the agenda isn't a big deal; it's mainly in the interest of avoiding scrolling / switching between agenda views.

Comment: This is a really nice idea, even if it's not currently possible.  Seems like we need a feature-request tracker for org.  :)

Comment: @ebpa unclear whether you can adapt the concepts in the following url: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40629/outline-minor-mode-folding-enhancements-wanted

Answer (score 1):

As erikstokes said, and as much as I know, you can not fold it (*)

But you can - and probably should, given your apparent needs - filter by `:tag:` (`/`), or by `:CATEGORY:` (`<`), or by some of a few more criteria. Check it at WORG, org-mode's wiki: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/agenda-filters.html

(*) well... you probably can code something, after all, it is Emacs, right? But I assume that is not the point here :-)